# MYSQL sort oder

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM stoc WHERE tip='$t' ORDER BY codint ASC LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
```

And the result is

```
Acer1
Acer10
Acer11
Acer12
Acer2
```

and i want

```
Acer1
Acer2
Acer10
Acer11
Acer12
```

eny idea ?

Comment: I suspect you're going to want to add a separate column for maintaining your custom sort order.  Which would have the benefit of allowing you to change that order at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering both by the length of the column and the column it self.

```
SELECT * FROM stoc WHERE tip='$t'
ORDER BY LENGTH(codint),codint LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit"
```

Though this might have a problem if other strings rather then `Acer...` exist.

If they do exist, I think you need to split down the string into string and number , and then `order by string,number`

Answer (score 0):

I've fix it. It gets last digit and order by them: http://rextester.com/OWE75092

```
SELECT `temp`, 
convert(
right(
     `temp`,
     CHAR_LENGTH(`temp`) - Least(
                                Locate('0',concat(`temp`, '0')),
                                Locate('1',concat(`temp`, '1')),
                                Locate('2',concat(`temp`, '2')),
                                Locate('3',concat(`temp`, '3')),
                                Locate('4',concat(`temp`, '4')),
                                Locate('5',concat(`temp`, '5')),
                                Locate('6',concat(`temp`, '6')),
                                Locate('7',concat(`temp`, '7')),
                                Locate('8',concat(`temp`, '8')),
                                Locate('9',concat(`temp`, '9'))
                           ) +1 ), UNSIGNED INTEGER) as myInt

FROM Table1
order by myInt;
```

Comment: Very close but if not found will return 0 http://rextester.com/NRSRUM8836

Comment: Thank you! I've fix it! and put demo!

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a **[function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146942/remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-field)** to remove non numeric chars

I easy duplicate to create the clone to remove the numeric chars, changing:

```
IF SUBSTR(as_val,i,1) NOT IN .... 
                      ^^^^^^
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/HXQ36170)**

```
SELECT `t`,
        uf_no_digits(`t`) as name,
        CONVERT(uf_only_digits(`t`), SIGNED) as ID

FROM Table1
ORDER BY name, ID
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'A2' x UNION SELECT 'A11' ORDER BY x;
+-----+
| x   |
+-----+
| A11 |
| A2  |
+-----+

SELECT 'A2' x UNION SELECT 'A11' ORDER BY x+0;
+-----+
| x   |
+-----+
| A2  |
| A11 |
+-----+
```